# System.Net.HttpStatusCode not generating on DTO

Tags: servicestack

In several of my models I am storing the System.Net.HttpStatusCode like so:

```cs
public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; set; }
```

When generating DTO file with SS typescript service, enums that I have specified myself are generated, but HttpStatusCode is left out which causes a typescript error.

I assume system types are being filtered out.  Is only option to refactor this to my own type/string or can I make it generate the typescript of this enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got system type generating by adding this to apphost configure method:

```cs
var nativeTypes = this.GetPlugin<NativeTypesFeature>();
nativeTypes.MetadataTypesConfig.ExportTypes.Add(typeof(System.Net.HttpStatusCode));
```